# Can you pass multiple glob strings to vscode findFiles api

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to ignore folders that have been excluded in the workspace settings when I call the api `findFiles` (https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration), however I'm not sure how to do this. I have tried looking for a way to combine glob statements but I haven't had much luck. I've found the GLOB_BRACE examples, but I don't think that will work in this case.

(e.g. glob("{foo/*.cpp,bar/*.cpp}", GLOB_BRACE))

Is there a way to pass multiple directories to the glob statement in findFiles to ignore?

I ideally would like to do something like this...

```
let search_config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration( "search" );
let search_exclude_settings = search_config.get( "exclude" );
let exclude_properties = "{";
for ( var exclude in search_exclude_settings ) {
    if( search_exclude_settings.hasOwnProperty( exclude ) ) {
        exclude_properties += exclude + ",";
    }
}
exclude_properties += filename_and_extension + "}";

var files = vscode.workspace.findFiles(filename_search, exclude_properties, 100);
```

but unfortunately that doesn't work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! I do apologise if I'm probably missing something blindingly obvious.

Thank you for your time!

Tom

Comment: I just confirmed in the VSCode source that it does not account for excluded files. I'd consider this a bug or a missing feature, which I am going to submit.

Comment: In the meantime, another approach might be to use then() to manually filter the results instead of trying the generate a glob.

Comment: Hi Seairth! Thank you very much for clarifying this, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious! Thanks for looking into this. If you have opened an issue/request for this would you be able to add the link here and I can give it a +1 ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so it turns out the code example I listed above does actually work and I just hadn't realised it *face palm*

I had a quick look at the vscode source and in src/vs/base/commom/glob.ts there are some examples of the regex expressions you can use and how they're parsed. Using '{' and then ',' as separators is handled correctly.